# Deleting CodeArtifact versions from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-codeartifact

My package name has a special character (`@`) in it which is throwing a validation error when attempting to delete the version(s) using the command line interface. Is there any way around this without changing the package name? I've tried delimiting the slash and also surrounding the package name with quotes (single and double), but am having no luck.

What I've tried:

```
aws codeartifact delete-package-versions --domain my-domain --repo npm-store --format npm --package @org/some-package-name --versions 0.5.1 0.3.1
```

Error from CLI:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DeletePackageVersions operation: 1 validation error detected: Value '@org/some-package-name' at 'packageName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [^!#/\s]+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `--namespace` flag and removing the `@` from the org name, I was able to get this working:

```
aws codeartifact delete-package-versions --domain my-domain --repo npm-store --format npm --namespace org --package some-package-name --versions 0.5.1 0.5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python modules:

```
aws codeartifact delete-package-versions --domain codeflex --repo codeartifact --format pypi --package helloworld --versions 0.0.3
```